# are form actions affected if you add the pound symbol to the url?

Tags: php, html

Can I add the pound symbol to form actions. For example, lets say that my form submits to forumsumbit.com, would it affect anything if I make it submit to forumsubmit.com#PostID2

```
<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>?pageAction=POSTS" method="post" name="forum" id="addpost" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

So that this, becomes this.

```
<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>?pageAction=POSTS#PostID2" method="post" name="forum" id="addpost" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I want to do this, because I want the page to scroll to that section oft he page after it reloads.

Also, using the pound sign in urls have a specific name?

Answer (score 1):

No. The part following the pound sign (called the "hash") is not processed by the server (unless you deliberately do something very strange to your server configuration). Having a hash in the URL won't affect anything about form processing, but it will cause the browser to jump to the named part of the page when the action page loads.